# how to set state while opening bottom sheet in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

So I'm having an issue with a bottom sheet that I'm trying to display.

the idea is that i want to display a bottom sheet and remove my bottom navigation bar when the bottom sheet shows. anyway, I've made a boolean called sheetOpen which is set to false initially and the idea is to set it to true in order to close the bottom navigation bar when the sheet pops up .
doing so without using setstate does not reflect any changes to the UI . But if I use set state in the show Bottom sheet function the app crashes and i get this message : 'Looking up deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. at this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable . to safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.'
I have tried multiple solutions(Stateful Builder, calling _controller.setstate ..) but nothing works.
Been stuck at this for 3 days..
anyway i will show the code that i have written and i would really appreciate anyone who can help.

```
  class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static bool sheetOpen = false;
  static int selectedIndex = 0;
  const FeedScreen();
  @override
  _FeedScreenState createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  late final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key;
  late PersistentBottomSheetController _controller;
  void _showPreview(
      final BuildContext context,
) {

//this is what's causing the issue
    setState(() {
      FeedScreen.sheetOpen = true;
    });

    _controller = _key.currentState!.showBottomSheet(
      (ctx) {
    //etc....
}



    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    //....
     bottomNavigationBar: FeedScreen.sheetOpen
            ? null
            : BottomNavBar(
                FeedScreen.selectedIndex,
                _changeTab,
              ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html?

you can wrap Stateful builder with Bottomsheet to use setState.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with statefulbuilder

```
StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
       return BottomNavBar(
            FeedScreen.selectedIndex,
            _changeTab,
          );}
```